# Is it productive to work on weekends?

Tags: productivity

My Ph.D. supervisor told me to go to the office every day except Thursday and stay there as long as he was in the building. I.e., work in the office rather than remotely. Generally, he stays there from 10:00 am to 07:00 pm.

Working 9 hours every day is already a lot. Therefore, I am thinking of not working during weekends at all. I will hang out with my friends, etc.

Is it a good idea to work on weekends? Or, could it be a cause for burnout? Or, should I increase my working hours during the weekdays?

Comment: What is the field?

Comment: @Buffy, CS + Chem.

Comment: Theoretical chemistry or lab based?

Comment: @Buffy, no, simulation.

Comment: *"stay there as long as he was in the building."* Frankly, that sounds like a completely ridiculous requirement. (But unfortunately I don't have good advice on how to resolve this.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me ask a different question. Is it productive for you to sit in an office for 9 hours every day staring at a screen with no ideas coming? Or does that sitting and staring at the screen result in advancing some result regularly?

The answer for me would be "absolutely not" to the first part. The answer for your advisor might be "yes, certainly" to the second.

We are all different. I'm guessing that your prof doesn't spend all that time on their research, unless they have many things going at once and can use one project to take a break from another.

For most of us, maybe you, the mind works best if we take breaks. For me, who spends a lot of time at a screen, breaks are essential. When I was working hard, I took lots of breaks. Short (coffee), long (25-50 mile bike rides). Yes, I worked weekends when family didn't require my attention, but basically on the same sort of "work til you get blocked, take a break". And inspiration for the current research might come while on the bike often enough, while my brain wasn't being over tasked, but was being fed by good blood flow.

Have you ever woken in the morning with some new insight into a knotty problem? It is pretty common. In fact, the brain never stops working unless you force it to stall, stuck at the same point, unable to move forward because it is too focused on an unproductive thread. You (me, at least) need to break that cycle.

I feel sorry for you that an advisor is pushing you to a way of working that doesn't work for everyone, though it might for them. But, it is probably a poor career move to anger an advisor. And I'm sorry that I can't intervene on your behalf, but it really seems counterproductive, not just unproductive, to force someone to work that way.

I don't know what options you have, however. Good luck.

---

Hmmm. Do they just turn their brain off on Thursday? Odd. I sometimes have a productive thought on Thursday, actually.